# Git post commit: skip --amend and rebase

Tags: git, githooks, post-commit-hook

I have a post-commit hook that does stuff in ruby. It works very well but in some cases I would like to skip the code execution when I do a `git rebase` or `git commit --amend`.

Does someone have an idea how I could not trigger the post-commit hook in these cases or any work around?

Comment: I can't cause this hook to run with `git commit --amend`, and I'm pretty confident it's never happened to me. I'm curious to know whether that's still an issue for you, and in what circumstances it happens?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65610742/1098683

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When rebasing, there's a directory called `rebase-merge` present in the `.git` folder. That could be an approach to disable the hook during a `rebase` (the start of a `rebase` btw is indicated by the `pre-rebase` hook).

Regarding the `--amend` however, I can't help you.

Comment: You mean detect the presence of the folder or something like that?

Comment: Yes. Don't know ruby enough to be able to present an example but surely you could also check in ruby whether there's a folder called `../rebase-merge` (relative to the hook directory) when your post-commit hook gets called

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect git commit --amend from a hook, this is your best option

bash

```
if [[ $(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID) == "git commit --amend" ]]; then
    echo "always allow git commit --amend"
    exit 0
fi
```

ruby

```
parent=`ps -ocommand= -p #{Process.ppid}`.chomp
if parent == "git commit --amend"
  # Always allow an amend
  puts "always allow git commit --amend"
  exit 0
end
```

git and shell aliases are expanded in the shell output, so this covers those cases too

Inspiration: https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/issues/146

Comment: This solution would miss some cases if there were any other command line flags supplied to git.

Comment: That's fair! It has been four years since I wrote this, though I think I can modify it to handle that situation... Perhaps instead of seeing what the parent process is equal to, we could see what it contains? So for bash change `"git commit --amend"` to `*"git"*"commit"*"--amend"*` and for ruby do something similar

Comment: For ruby perhaps do something similar, maybe change `== "git commit --amend"` to `=~ /git.*commit.*--amend.*/`, I'm too many laptops away from the original problem I was solving but hopefully that helps if you were attempting something similar and hit this issue regarding flags