# How to detect commit --amend by pre-commit hook ?

Tags: git, githooks

When I do commit --amend, it is unsafe commit if the commit already has been pushed to remote repository.

I want to detect unsafe commit --amend by pre-commit hook and abort.

But pre-commit hook has no arguments. I don't know how to detect --amend.

What should I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git post commit: skip --amend and rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367722/git-post-commit-skip-amend-and-rebase)

Comment: Related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56443617/13762264 The accepted answer suggests the approach isn't to stop `git commit --amend` but to stop people doing `git push --force`

Answer (score 19):

Following @Roger Dueck's answer, ended up doing:

```
#./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

IS_AMEND=$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -e '--amend');

if [ -n "$IS_AMEND" ]; then
  return;
fi
```

Comment: Maybe it is more readable, but that would fail if `-e` option is set for the current shell. Use instead: `if ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | grep -q -e '--amend'; then ...; fi`

Comment: In my case of zsh at macOS i had to use `exit 0` instead of `return`

Comment: For me `$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID)` returns `/bin/sh .husky/prepare-commit-msg .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG commit HEAD`.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR version: there's a script below (kind of in the middle) that enforces a particular work-flow that may work for you, or may not.  It doesn't exactly prevent particular `git commit --amend`s (plus you can always use `--no-verify` to skip the script), and it does prevent (or at least warn about) other `git commit`s, which may or may not be what you want.

To make it error-out instead of warning, change `WARNING` to `ERROR` and change `sleep 5` to `exit 1`.

**EDIT**: erroring-out is not a good idea, because you can't tell, in this git hook, that this is an "amend" commit, so this will fail (you have to add `--no-verify`) if you're simply adding a new commit to a branch that has an upstream and is at the upstream's head.

---

It's not *necessarily* unsafe, because `git commit --amend` does not actually *change* any commits in your repo, it just adds a new, different commit and re-points the branch tip there.  For instance, if your branch looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D      <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - F  <-- HEAD=branch, origin/branch
```

then what a successful `git commit --amend` does is this:

```
A - B - C - D      <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - F  <-- origin/branch
              \
                G  <-- HEAD=branch
```

You still have commit `F`, and commit `G` is the "amended" version of `F`.  However, it's true that `G` is not a "fast forward" of `F` and you probably should not `git push -f origin branch` in this case.

A similar cases occurs if you're *already* in that kind of situation, i.e., after that successful `git commit --amend` (done without or in spite of the script below):

```
A - B - C - D       <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - F   <-- origin/branch
              \
                G   <-- HEAD=branch
```

If you now `git commit` (even without `--amend`), you'll add a new commit, e.g., `G` connects to `H`; but again, attempting to push `H` is a non-fast-forward.

You can't specifically test for `--amend`, but you can check whether there is an "upstream", and if so, whether the current `HEAD` is an ancestor of that upstream.  Here's a slightly cheesy pre-commit hook that does this (with a warning-and-sleep rather than an error-exit).

```
#!/bin/sh

# If initial commit, don't object
git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD >/dev/null || exit 0

# Are we on a branch?  If not, don't object
branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD) || exit 0

# Does the branch have an upstream?  If not, don't object
upstream=$(git rev-parse -q --verify @{upstream}) || exit 0

# If HEAD is contained within upstream, object.
if git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD $upstream; then
    echo "WARNING: if amending, note that commit is present in upstream"
    sleep 5:
fi
exit 0
```

The basic problem here is that this situation occurs all the time even without using `git commit --amend`.  Let's say you start with the same setup as above, but commit `F` does not exist yet:

```
A - B - C - D      <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E      <-- HEAD=branch, origin/branch
```

Now you, in your copy of the repo, decide to work on `branch`.  You fix a bug and `git commit`:

```
A - B - C - D      <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E      <-- origin/branch
              \
                F  <-- HEAD=branch
```

You're now ahead of `origin` and `git push origin branch` would do the right thing.  But while you were fixing one bug, Joe fixes a different bug in *his* copy of the repo, and pushes *his* version to `origin/branch`, beating you to the `push` step.  So you run `git fetch` to update and you now have this:

```
A - B - C - D      <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - J  <-- origin/branch
              \
                F  <-- HEAD=branch
```

(where `J` is Joe's commit).  This is a perfectly normal state, and it would be nice to be able to `git commit` to add another fix (for, say, a third bug) and then either merge or rebase to include Joe's fix too.  The example pre-commit hook will object.

If you always rebase-or-merge *first*, then add your third fix, the script won't object.  Let's look at what happens when we get into the `F`-and-`J` situation above and use `git merge` (or a `git pull` that does a merge):

```
A - B - C - D             <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - J         <-- origin/branch
              \   \
                F - M     <-- HEAD=branch
```

You are now at commit `M`, the merge, which is "ahead of" `J`.  So the script's `@{upstream}` finds commit `J` and checks whether the `HEAD` commit (`M`) is an ancestor of `J`.  It's not, and additional new commits are allowed, so your "fix third bug" commit `N` gives you this:

```
A - B - C - D             <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - J         <-- origin/branch
              \   \
                F - M - N <-- HEAD=branch
```

Alternatively you can `git rebase` onto `J`, so that before you go to fix the third bug you have:

```
A - B - C - D          <-- master, origin/master
          \
            E - J      <-- origin/branch
              \  \
              (F) F'   <-- HEAD=branch
```

(here `F'` is the cherry-picked commit `F`; I put parentheses around `F` to indicate that, while it's still in your repo, it no longer has any branch label pointing to it, so it's mostly invisible.)  Now the pre-commit hook script won't object, again.

Comment: Broken. Suppose HEAD is same as origin/branch. Now if I add a new commit (no amend) " git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD $upstream " would see it as amend :(

Comment: @BinTAN-Victor: Yes, see the line beginning with **EDIT**. To allow that condition, exit zero if the two names identify the same hash ID. In general I don't recommend this whole approach, though: see the notes at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to detect a "pure" amend in the pre-commit hook:

```
if git diff --cached --quiet ; then
  echo "This is a pure amend"
else
  echo "This is a commit with changes"
fi
```

By "pure" I mean you're only rewriting the commit message and not any of the changes in the commit. If there are any changes in your index when you call `git commit --amend`, you're rewriting more than the commit message and this will behave as if you're doing a conventional `git commit`.

Comment: Nice but big BUT

Comment: This would probably trigger for a normal commit with `--allow-empty` too.

Answer (score 2):

Following @perror's answer, I came up with the following:

```
parent=$(/bin/ps -o ppid -p $PPID | tail -1)
if [ -n "$parent" ]; then
    amended=$(/bin/ps -o command -p $parent | grep -e '--amend')
    if [ -n "$amended" ]; then
        echo "This is an 'amend'"
    fi  
fi
```

Comment: I'm using git bash in windows. And this return error "ps: unknown option --o". Do you have any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if this is an `--amend` case, in standard shell:

```
git_command=$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID)
if [ -z "${git_command##git\ commit*--amend*}" ]; then
    echo "The original command was a: git commit --amend"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but pointed me in the right direction.  See my own answer, which checks for '--amend' in the parent process.

Comment: Hum, I might have  used some hypothesis on the context without noticing it! Sorry for that. But, I am happy that you succeeded (and thanks for sharing your answer!).

Answer (score 0):

as documented in [prepare-commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg):

> It takes one to three parameters. The first is the name of the file that contains the commit log message. The second is the source of the commit message, and can be: message; ...

> or commit, followed by a commit object name (if a -c, -C or --amend option was given)

so i've used

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$2" = "commit" -a "$3" = "HEAD" ] && echo "ignore amend or do something"
```