# Make git prevent amends to pushed commits

Tags: git

Is it possible to have git check the remote branch in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook and see if the current commit is an amend, and if so, abort the commit?
That way it makes sure that you can not amend a commit that you already pushed, which would be handy.

Comment: Either you're forbidding rewriting history altogether, or you don't. But an amended commit is just *a different commit*. On which basis do you intend to differentiate your "amends"?

Comment: when you commit using --amend, it doesn't change the commit. if you already pushed, you can't push the amended commit again unless you --force. i want to prevent amending commits before that happens, as then you have to do cleanup, or screw over everyone who already checked out the not amended commit.

Comment: That's precisely the misunderstanding I was suspecting : I have to insist, **yes**, using `--amend` very much changes the commit. So much so that it's even arguably indistinguishable from any other commit in the tree after the amend. That's the reason for the needed `--force`. You're discarding the old commit and replacing it with the new, but git is not aware that the new one is the result of an amend. It's just *a different commit*.

Comment: Have you figured a way to do precisely that which you are asking, regardless of the counter-productive suggestions that you can't, or that you shouldn't ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to prevent someone doing `git commit --amend` on their own machine.

You can however prevent people from force pushing `git push --force` and rewriting the repository history. This is done with a server side hook e.g. see Github's [Blocking force pushes to a repository](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/developer-workflow/blocking-force-pushes-to-a-repository).

Comment: i thought one might be able to do some fancy shell scripting to figure out it's an amend.

Comment: You can ask people to use a [pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986190/1602555) but that's IMHO counter productive. It will be better to educate them that `push --force` is not allowed and rewriting history is a bad idea.