# Prevent "pre-commit" hook from looping

Tags: git

### Description

I have created an algorithm to read the commit message, and depending if it contains "fix", "add", or "break", I edit the version in a file to increase the minor/major/patch number.

For this purpose, I have created 2 hooks:

- "commit-msg", which will analyze the commit message, and bump the version in the file (ok)
- "post-commit", which is supposed to add the edited file containing the bumped version to the last commit (infinite loop issue)

Here is the content of the "post-commit" hook:

```sh
echo "adding bumped file to the last commit"
git add haxelib.json
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

When using `git commit -m "fix typo"`, the "post-commit" hook will loop without any interruption.

### Question

How can I prevent "post-commit" git hook from firing when running `git commit`?

Comment: I think you can add `--no-verify` to bypass git hooks https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: I tried, but it is ignored for post-commit hook. It only work for the `pre-commit` hook unfortunately...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git skip post-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610742/git-skip-post-commit-hook)

Comment: The answer looks to be that, no, there isn’t an easy way to skip a post-commit hook

Comment: For anyone passing by, the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610742/git-skip-post-commit-hook does not solves my issue at all (I don't know why it has been marked as duplicate). Here is the solution I found (sorry, I can't write it better since the issue has been closed): 

`
if [[ $VERIFY_POST_COMMIT = 0 ]]
then
    exit 0
fi

echo "adding bumped file to the last commit"
git add haxelib.json
VERIFY_POST_COMMIT=0 git commit --amend --no-edit` The trick is to use an environment variable (`chmod -x will not work in this case`).

Comment: nice solution. I’m glad you found a way to prevent the post commit hook